# Google Calendar jquery lists all-day events on the wrong day

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-calendar-api

I was looking for something that would allow me to pull events from a public google calendar and display it as an event list. I came across a jquery script that meet this need and allowed for customization of its appearance (css), but there is one issue. For events that are "all-day" on the google calendar, they are being displayed a day earlier, ie.. an event on the 4th is showing as being on the 3rd.

I have little experience with jquery so any guidance/direction on what may need to be changed or altered in the script to correct is greatly appreciated.

```
(function(t, e, n, a) {
    "use strict";
    var i = "google_calendar_events";
    var s = {
        key: null,
        calendar: null,
        max: 7
    };
    function r(e, n) {
        this.element = e;
        this.settings = t.extend({}, s, n);
        this.init();
    }
    r.prototype.init = function() {
        var t = this;
        if (!t.settings.key || !t.settings.calendar) {
            return false;
        }
        t.getCalendarEvents();
    };
    r.prototype.getCalendarEvents = function() {
        var e = this;
        e.settings.apiUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/" + e.settings.calendar + "/events";
        t.get(e.settings.apiUrl, {
            maxResults: e.settings.max,
            singleEvents: true,
            orderBy: "startTime",
            timeMin: new Date().toISOString(),
            key: e.settings.key
        }, function(t) {
            if (t.hasOwnProperty("items")) {
                e.build(t.items);
            }
        });
    };
    r.prototype.build = function(e) {
        var n = this;
        t(n.element).html('<ul class="eventlist"></ul>');
        for (var a = 0; a < e.length; a++) {
            var i = e[a];
            var s = !i.start.hasOwnProperty("dateTime");
            var r = s ? new Date(i.start.date) : new Date(i.start.dateTime);
            var o = "<li>";
            if (i.summary && i.htmlLink) {
                o += '<div class="g_day_div">' + n.formatDate(r, s) + '</div>';
            }
                o += '<div class="event_title">' + '<a href="' + i.htmlLink + '" rel="' + i.summary + '">' + i.summary + '</a>' + '</div>';
            if (i.location) {
                o += '<div class="location">' + i.location + '</div>';
            }
            if (i.description) {
                o += '<div class="description">' + i.description + '</div>';
            }
            o += "</li>";
            t(n.element).find("ul.eventlist").append(o);
        }
    };
    r.prototype.formatDate = function(t, e) {
        t = t instanceof Date ? t : new Date(t);
        var n = [ "Sun", "Mon", "Tues", "Weds", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat" ];
        var a = [ "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" ];
        var i = t.getHours();
        var s = t.getMinutes();
        var r = i > 11 ? "pm" : "am";
        i = i > 12 ? i - 12 : i;
        s = s < 10 ? "0" + s : s;
        var o = i + ":" + s + r;
        var l = '<div class="g_month">' + a[t.getMonth()] + '</div>' + '<div class="g_day">' + t.getDate() + '</div>';
        return e ? l : l;
    };
    t.fn[i] = function(e) {
        return this.each(function() {
            if (!t.data(this, "plugin_" + i)) {
                t.data(this, "plugin_" + i, new r(this, e));
            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

Comment: Hi LinPren, may you please point me to the resource you used to obtain this script. I too am looking for access to a private calendar that gives be all events in an array of dates that I can use for jQuery datepicker.

Comment: Hello LinPren, could you provide any other code needed in order to execute this script? (i.e. HTML file, or any other script it may need)

Comment: here is the html that uses the script [link] https://evansvillelutheranschool.com/TEMP/demo.html

Comment: and it also uses jquery 3.3.1-min.js at [link] https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js

Comment: LinPren: Thanks a lot for providing these links. I have visited the URL and the result i obtain is the following: https://i.imgur.com/mCF0WXt.png . The dates seem to be right on my end. Could you please help me identify the issue you are having? Cheers

Comment: interesting, cause this is what I see https://imgur.com/UyX4XVp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are having is because of Time-zones. When you call `new Date(...)` a date object is created - but be aware that this object also holds time information (which in this case, is guessed based on your computer's timezone).

As an example, having my computer's date set to Los Angeles timezone, calling `new Date('2019-01-15')` yields the following date: Mon Jan 14 2019 16:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)

The Date constructor understands the date string as being UTC time, but calling the getDate, getHours, etc. functions will return the information based on your local timezone.

As a workaround, you can use the functions getUTCDate, getUTCHours, etc. See an adaptation of the code you provided below (the only function modified is r.prototype.formatDate):

```js
(function(t, e, n, a) {
    "use strict";
    var i = "google_calendar_events";
    var s = {
        key: null,
        calendar: null,
        max: 7
    };
    function r(e, n) {
        this.element = e;
        this.settings = t.extend({}, s, n);
        this.init();
    }
    r.prototype.init = function() {
        var t = this;
        if (!t.settings.key || !t.settings.calendar) {
            return false;
        }
        t.getCalendarEvents();
    };
    r.prototype.getCalendarEvents = function() {
        var e = this;
        e.settings.apiUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/" + e.settings.calendar + "/events";
        t.get(e.settings.apiUrl, {
            maxResults: e.settings.max,
            singleEvents: true,
            orderBy: "startTime",
            timeMin: new Date().toISOString(),
            key: e.settings.key
        }, function(t) {
            if (t.hasOwnProperty("items")) {
                e.build(t.items);
            }
        });
    };
    r.prototype.build = function(e) {
        var n = this;
        t(n.element).html('<ul class="eventlist"></ul>');
        for (var a = 0; a < e.length; a++) {
            var i = e[a];
            var s = !i.start.hasOwnProperty("dateTime");
            var r = s ? new Date(i.start.date) : new Date(i.start.dateTime);
            var o = "<li>";
            if (i.summary && i.htmlLink) {
                o += '<div class="g_day_div">' + n.formatDate(r, s) + '</div>';
            }
                o += '<div class="event_title">' + '<a href="' + i.htmlLink + '" rel="' + i.summary + '">' + i.summary + '</a>' + '</div>';
            if (i.location) {
                o += '<div class="location">' + i.location + '</div>';
            }
            if (i.description) {
                o += '<div class="description">' + i.description + '</div>';
            }
            o += "</li>";
            t(n.element).find("ul.eventlist").append(o);
        }
    };
    r.prototype.formatDate = function(t, e) {
        t = t instanceof Date ? t : new Date(t);
        var n = [ "Sun", "Mon", "Tues", "Weds", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat" ];
        var a = [ "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" ];
        var i = t.getUTCHours();
        var s = t.getUTCMinutes();
        var r = i > 11 ? "pm" : "am";
        i = i > 12 ? i - 12 : i;
        s = s < 10 ? "0" + s : s;
        var o = i + ":" + s + r;
        var l = '<div class="g_month">' + a[t.getUTCMonth()] + '</div>' + '<div class="g_day">' + t.getUTCDate() + '</div>';
        return e ? l : l;
    };
    t.fn[i] = function(e) {
        return this.each(function() {
            if (!t.data(this, "plugin_" + i)) {
                t.data(this, "plugin_" + i, new r(this, e));
            }
        });
    };
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

This will show the appropriate day no matter what the timezone is set to on your computer.

You can find more information about JavaScript's Date [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Comment: thank you so much!! I figure time zone had something to do with once you told me that the dates were showing up correctly when you pulled it up.